# CSS relative positioning without setting parent to relative

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are threads on here that explain that position:relative in a parent element will make position:absolute in any child elements relative to the top left of the parent. Thats fine.

But what about when you don't want to set the parent to position:relative ?  In a fairly standard forms system I'm having the problem that position:relative has two meanings:

1. It determines how this element is positioned and
2. It changes how the children of this element are positioned if their positioning is absolute.

But I want 2. without 1. I want the children to be relative to the parent but the parent may be positioned static, relative or absolute.

I suppose I could add an inner div inside the parent which does nothing except have position:relative, but that would be a pain and extra mess. Is there a better way or doing this ?

All positioning is done in jquery so a jquery only solution would be fine.

thanks

Comment: one simple solution is you need 2 wrappers. The first wrapper is the parent, the second wrapper is the ***only*** direct child of the parent (the first wrapper) and this second wrapper will contain all the children of the first wrapper. That way you can set the `position:relative` for the second wrapper while you can freely set `position` of the first wrapper to what you want.

Comment: position:relative positions the element relative to its normal (==static) position. without further css, theres no difference, so just use relative instead of static/nothing or use absolute when desired. in both cases child elements with position:relative should work as expected.

Comment: You don't need to change position to relative if it is already relative, fixed, or absolute. If it was static changing it to relative wont make any changes to element layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have asked and answered your own question here really.

> I suppose I could add an inner div inside the parent which does
>   nothing except have position:relative, but that would be a pain and
>   extra mess. Is there a better way or doing this?

An element can't have a hybrid of positions, so this is indeed the only solution; to create an additional element which allows you to combine the desired positional layouts.

> All positioning is done in jquery so a jquery only solution would be
>   fine.

If you had concerns about the cleanliness of the markup then adding the extra element via jquery may attract you. However, as an aspiring purist I tend to avoid using javascript for presentational aspects, strictly speaking this should be left to CSS wherever practical.

Comment: Thanks for this. Its a forms app where the html is generated at run time from db records, but still wanting to keep the markup generated as clean as possible so its easier for programmers to read and debug. Another possible is to extend jquery so the inner elements are positioned absolutely and the system calculates the relative offset from the parents offset.

Comment: With that approach you're shifting the complexity from the markup to the js, which programmers still have to read and understand.

Comment: OK so I've chosen this as the solution and actually gone for that in my code. I guess all the ideals around "semantic html" (remember that?) are broken when you're adding elements just to work around stuff, but cest la vie :)  thanks again.